# Detect OS and Java on Windows and Linux

Tags: maven, build, javafx, maven-3

I have a JavaFX project based on Maven. I want to build the Maven project on Windows and on Linux. In order to automate the process when I deploy the bundle I want to automatically detect the operating system.

In windows I have this configuration:

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But on Linux I have this configuration:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>/opt/java/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Can I somehow set the Java usage based on the operating system on which the bundle is deployed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for such purposes like this:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <name>Windows XP</name>
        <family>Windows</family>
        <arch>x86</arch>
        <version>5.1.2600</version>
      </os>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Do I need to set them manually or the OS will choose the appropriate one when the application is started.

Comment: The OS detection is done automatically. You can see that if you `mvn --version` in the last of the output you see the values you have on your os.