# Build JavaFX project on MacOS (m1 chip), run .jar file on windows 10

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I built a JavaFX chat project on my Mac M1 Pro, and when I build the project it won't run on my friends' windows 10 PC's. They try to run the .jar through cmd, but this is the error:

```
C:\Users\Ms\nokkeenkelt>java -jar GroupChat.jar
Oct 25, 2021 2:19:21 AM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @44f2c786'
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:245)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:262)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:286)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:160)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:661)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:681)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:274)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:286)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:160)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:661)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:681)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have included the JavaFX .dylib files in the build. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: `.dylib` files are only supported under MacOS (more or less), you need the windows `.dll` instead

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615864/how-to-make-maven-request-the-correct-javafx-dependancies-on-linux

Comment: You need to create the appropriate runtime image. Do [some research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823040/1155209).