# I cannot compile my javafx maven project on Raspberry pi

Tags: java, linux, maven, javafx, dependencies

I created a java project which compiles and runs fine on my mac with "mvn compile". But once I fetch it from gitlab on my Pi it won't compile on linux.

I consulted many pages but none seem to apply to this particular issue.

Can anyone help me? I would be really grateful!

The error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< SmartMirror:SmartMirror >-----------------------
[INFO] Building SmartMirror 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.816 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-23T14:54:44+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SmartMirror: Could not resolve dependencies for project SmartMirror:SmartMirror:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:19-ea+9, org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:${javafx.platform}:19-ea+9, org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:${javafx.platform}:19-ea+9, org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:jar:${javafx.platform}:19-ea+9: Failure to find org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:19-ea+9 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The POM.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SmartMirror</groupId>
    <artifactId>SmartMirror</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
        <javafx.platform>linux</javafx.platform>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+9</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+9</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The module-info.java file:

```
module SmartMirror {
    exports weather to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
    exports main to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
    
    opens weather to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
    opens main to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;

    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires transitive json;
}
```

Edit:

Thank you so far for your answers. Though the issue persists. Any more ideas?

Comment: Do `rm -r ~/.m2/repository/org/openjfx` and build again.  Sometimes repository caches get corrupted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make maven request the correct javafx dependancies on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615864/how-to-make-maven-request-the-correct-javafx-dependancies-on-linux)

Comment: Don’t use ea software unless you are testing latest dev software, which you are not.

Comment: The linux classifier is for Intel processors I think not pi.  I don’t know what pi uses but it is not intel. Different classifiers are [here maybe you want linux-aarch64](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/18.0.2/), but I don’t know. I advise you consult a dev guide specifically for creating JavaFX apps for pi using recent JavaFX stable releases.

Comment: Shading JavaFX applications to include the JavaFX framework is usually not recommended.  JavaFX is built to run as a modular project, also shading makes your module definition useless.

Comment: If you are trying to actually build the project on the pi it is probably unnecessary to specify the javafx.platform and use the classifiers as it will probably work out what to use from the environment (I’ve never tried that on a pi though, so I don’t know for sure).

Comment: @VGR I tried and it says "No such file or directory"...

Comment: @tgdavies I had already read this post, which is why I added the <classifier> to begin with. Before I had my POM.xml without the classifier and the same error occurred.

Comment: @jewelsea now I removed both the classifier and the shade and the same error occurs, even with a "mvn clean compile". What do you mean with ea sorfware?

Comment: ea stands for early access, the software version you chose is 19-ea+9, it is not production software and may not be stable.  The current JavaFX stable release is 18.0.2.  That is not the likely root cause of your issue though.

Comment: I found these [instructions for using JavaFX on a pi](https://docs.gluonhq.com/embedded/).  They are reasonably recent, but may be dated or not matching your pi version. They appear different from what you are doing.  Perhaps try following them and see if you can get the documented example app to work in your environment.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks the link, but it didn't work for me either... I changed from ea to the stable version you recommended and followed the instructions from the link you posted. Same error. I'm completely clueless and have no idea how to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I used this command on Raspberry Pi 3B (Raspberry Pi OS lite 32bit) :

```
mvn -Djavafx.platform=linux-arm32-monocle clean compile
```

if you use 64bit version :

```
mvn -Djavafx.platform=linux-aarch64-monocle clean compile
```