# Download JavaFX dependency using Ivy

Tags: java, javafx, maven-2, ivy, maven-central

I'm looking to fetch JavaFX from Maven Central using Ivy.

This works to get the Java dependencies, but not the native dependencies.

Expected:

- `javafx-graphics-21.0.1.jar`
- `javafx-graphics-21.0.1-linux.jar`

Actual:

- `javafx-graphics-21.0.1.jar`
- **MISSING** `javafx-graphics-21.0.1-linux.jar`

How do I also obtain the native components?

`ivy.xml`

```xml
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="https://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="org.my" module="my-proj"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.openjfx" name="javafx-graphics" rev="21.0.1" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

```bash
ivy && ls ~/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/jars
# javafx-graphics-21.0.1.jar
```

Here's the POM: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx/20.0.1/javafx-20.0.1.pom

Related: [How to make maven request the correct javafx dependancies on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615864)

I'm adding the `maven-2` tag because [Ivy uses the Maven 2 repositories](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/master/tutorial/start.html):

> With no specific settings, Ivy uses the Maven 2 repository to resolve the dependencies you declare in an Ivy file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First obtain the `javafx.platform` value of the native components from the [POM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx/20.0.1/javafx-20.0.1.pom).
2. Ensure the `ivy.xml` is configured to use the correct `xmlns:m`.
3. Add `m:classifier="linux"` (or `linux-aarch64`, `mac-aarch64`, etc).
4. Native platform jars should show in `.ivy2/cache`

`ivy.xml`

```xml
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="https://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="org.my" module="my-proj"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.openjfx" name="javafx-graphics" rev="21.0.1" />
        <dependency org="org.openjfx" name="javafx-graphics" rev="21.0.1" m:classifier="linux"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

```bash
ls ~/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/jars
# javafx-graphics-21.0.1.jar
# javafx-graphics-21.0.1-linux.jar
```