eclipse cannot import javafx-controls.jar from maven pom.xml
I want to import a maven project into eclipse that is working well with intellij. eclipse however reports errors with maven artifacts as shown below. I think the ${javafx.platform} substring is causing this error. This usually indicates that an environment variable could not be found. How am I supposed to supply that variable? Is this the cause for the behaviour anyway?
Missing artifact org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1   pom.xml /eclipse-jfx-test   line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
eclipse version:
Version: 2024-06 (4.32.0)
Build id: 20240606-1231
pom.xml as produced by maven artifact (project is yet empty):
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>r-uu</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipse-jfx-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <javafx.platform>win</javafx.platform>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>r_uu.eclipse_jfx_test.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                            <mainClass>r_uu.eclipse_jfx_test.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                            <mainClass>r_uu.eclipse_jfx_test.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>```


Could be related to your maven version.

Shouldn't that be javafx.controls.jar ?

Downvote? Why?
The file in my .m2 repository downloaded by maven is named "javafx-controls-22.0.1.jar". The maven artifact name is "javafx-controls". See the dependency copied from mvnrepository.com:
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>22.0.1</version>
</dependency>```

Please post your pom.xml.

@jewelsea: I tried in eclipse with external maven 3.9.6 (recommended on the post you gave) and with 3.9.7.  Unfortunately without luck. You mentioned setting a system property -Djavafx.platform=win. Where am I supposed to provide that environment value? When starting eclipse? In a (maven) run configuration? In a JRE environment?

@David Weber: updated post

As an aside, the current javafx-maven-plugin is <version>0.0.8</version>.

JavaFX 22 requires a minimum Java version of 17, not 11.  Your JavaFX maven plugin version is out of date.   Though I don’t know that those are your only issues.

“ Where am I supposed to provide that environment value? ” -> you don’t.  Use a compatible maven version < 3.9.7 and the JavaFX parent pom used by all JavaFX dependencies will set the platform automatically using a maven profile that is automatically triggered by the platform detected for your build machine.  Get it working from the command line outside eclipse first.



switched back to maven 3.9.6 (that repairs mvn install which did not work any more with 3.9.7)


double checked that eclipse uses external maven 3.9.6


changed java.version,  compiler.source and compiler.target to 22


changed version of javafx-maven-plugin to 0.0.8


As said above: maven build from command line now works, but still no changes in eclipse.

@r-uu If it works outside Eclipse, use that to build for now.  As I do not use Eclipse, I don't have much advice for building JavaFX with Maven inside Eclipse.  Get the hello world project in the getting started instructions at openjfx.io working in your environment.  Consider using a Java version that includes JavaFX ("Full JDK" in Liberica or "JDK FX" in Zulu).

I'm seeing a similar issue. It's complaining about "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1" and if you look in your local .m2 repo you'll see it's trying to add a jar called "javafx-controls-21.0.1-${javafx.platform}.jar.lastUpdated". The issue seems to be that it can't resolve the OS classifier. This can be added by way of "win" in the dependency, but I've not found this to work. I've also gone back to Maven 3.9.6 and pointed to this in Eclipse, and it still doesn't work. For me, Eclipse 2024-06 for JavaFX/Maven is broken.

BTW - I can't get 2024-06 working but 2024-03 does. Maybe we'll have to wait till 2024-09 for this to be fixed?

A similar issue seems to be discussed here, but the suggested solutions do not work in my environment, either. I'll try 2024-03, too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615864/how-to-make-maven-request-the-correct-javafx-dependancies-on-linux

Another solution: Ditch Eclipse for IntelliJ. I downloaded IntelliJ Community Edition 2024.1.4 [latest version as of today] and opened up a project with a pom.xml and it worked seamlessly. The same Java/JavaFX pom.xml fails with the above reported issues in Eclipse 2024-06 but works fine with IntelliJ 2024.1.4.

Sometimes in my environment intellij fails to start javafx programs with java.lang.module.FindException, other times the same programs run smoothly. Projects are always imported from maven. Maven runs without problems from a shell.
And yes, I really need that jpms stuff. I just started looking at netbeans now ...

believe it or not. netbeans seems to do a perfect job right from the start. just import (major multi module) maven project with jpms activated and javafx (version 22, java and javafx) seem to work immediately without any intervention. investigating netbeans further now ...

I now what you mean about NetBeans as I've also tried it. I see Eclipse creates its own dirs/files [.settings, .classpath,.project] and IntelliJ [.ideas], whereas NetBeans doesn't. It's as though it works entirely with the pom.xml file and closer to the Maven build. We can't always choose which IDE to use if you are part of a team and it's a personal thing also. I do find IntelliJ a really well-thought out and solid IDE. I'm not so keen on the NetBean's debugger, but again what I'm probably used to.

I get the " java.lang.module.FindException" from time to time and usually a Maven cmdline build resolves it. It can reflect slight differences between Maven and the IDE. Also, IDEs can differ if your build structure doesn't conform 100% to the standard build structure of src/main/java, .... src/main/resources ... They expect to see this standard Java and Maven structure and suspect sometimes they get a bit confused if things aren't exactly where they expect.
